# Laravel: Model Class not found in relationships

Tags: php, orm, laravel-5.3

Using Relationships first time and having issue to understand it.

I have a `Student` Class and a `Course` Model Class. A student can take many courses. In `Student` Model I do this:

```
public function course()
    {        
        return $this->belongsTo('Course');
    }
```

and in controller when I do this: `.$student->course()->course_title` it gives an error:

```
FatalThrowableError in Model.php line 779:
Class 'Course' not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Something wrong in here through. I think that a `Student` can take many `Courses` and a `Course` can have many `Students`. So it need to using `belongsToMany` instead of belongsTo

Comment: Edited/updated my response. Please see below

Answer (score 2):

replace your code with it

```
public function course()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Course::class);
}
```

Comment: `belongsTo` takes a string as Classname

Comment: @Volatil3 I can confirm it works

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your namespace in your `Course` class matches 'App\Models'. You might be trying to access an "empty" namespace.

Namespaces are declared at the top of your class file. So for example:

Course.php:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
...


class Course extends Model { ... }
```

OtherClass.php

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
...


class OtherClass extends Model { 

...

    public function course()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Course')
    }

}
```

Please note that the namespace declared at the top of Course.php matches the path provided to the relationship method (return) `belongsTo()`. You can also provide `Course::class` to the belongsTo method, but you need to import aka `use` the class in your php class.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i solved it by adding a name space in the top of my model

for your case,

```
use \App\Course ; // Your name space of your class in relation
```

Hope this help others

NB : I used Laravel 5.0